# Is it possible to download a CGI application

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I'm running an Apache 2.2 server, and I configured cgi applications to work properly in the folder /cgi-bin.
I was wondering what someone could do in order to "download" the application instead of executing it. 
Is it possible that some misconfiguration can lead to such a scenario?

Comment: Yes, if the web-server *serves* the resources as *static content* then they could be downloaded. For this reason, most "special" directories are explicitly prevented (under sane settings, but check your configuration!) from being used for static content or directory listings.

Comment: it surely can and does happen somewhere. [here's](http://www.w3.org/Security/faq/wwwsf4.html) a starting point cgi script security